# React - как убрать определнные даты с datepicker'a

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

Я получаю определённый массив с датой типа `let excludedDates = [{12/12/2022},{11/12/2022},{10/12/2022},]`  и мне нужно как то указать в datepicker'e что даты в этом массиве должны быть disabled,использую https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-exclude-dates

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Судя по документации (скриншот который вы сделали) у вас дата должна быть Date, следовательно вам нужно перевести из значение из string в Date

```
let excludedDates = ["12/12/2022","11/12/2022","10/12/2022"].map(el => new Date(el))
```

P.S: не совсем понимаю что означает `{12/12/2022}` но предполагаю что это строка